# Is there a way to start all QUnit tests from different projects at the same time in SAP WebIDE?

Tags: sapui5, qunit

I have different projects in my SAP WebIDE and each one have it's own QUnit-tests. When I will running my QUnit-tests, I can start it for each project seperately. But is there a way, that I can start all QUnit-test for all my projects with one click, so that I have one result page?

If there is no way for that in the WebIDE, is there a way in the ABAP-System, where the files are deployt?

Thanks.

Comment: You can do that by creating re-use library. Add all your projects into one single library, and implement unit tests for that single library. However, my question is why you want to do this? Because using re-use lib and implementing OPA5 for it is time-consuming.

Comment: Hey Vortex, thanks for your idea. But this is an additional overhead, as you say. We already have the tests in the different projects and the idea was to check them centrally to get a result of all of our projects.